# Unable to install expect utility in Linux

Tags: linux, installation, expect, yum

I'm trying to install `expect` utility in my Linux machine, using below command:

`sudo yum install expect`

But getting below error:

```
# sudo yum install expect
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/blacklist.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin blacklist
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin fastestmirror
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/product-id.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin product-id
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/refresh-packagekit.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin refresh-packagekit
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhui-lb.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin rhui-lb
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin subscription-manager
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/whiteout.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin whiteout
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
```

I googled over the internet for this issue , but no clue.

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: which distribution do you use?

Comment: Red Hat 4.4.6-4

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider installing a newer version of RedHat. The 4.x is no longer supported. One idea though, is if you still want to use your version of RedHat, is to install expect directly from the CD.

Answer (score 0):

You could install from source. You'll have to start with Tcl (https://tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html), then do Expect (https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index)